# PHP, Get file_get_contents from webpage & compare

Tags: php

I am getting an error on this:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://segeco.me/lol.txt');
if ($homepage == ('loll')) then
echo $homepage;
?>
```

ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/bluesnow/public_html/dog.php on line 5

(The code is not php, Just an example.)

Comment: Also, How can i fetch this from the internet?, For example i want to fetch a txt from dropbox.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` just returns a string.  Check the docs: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: UPDATED THE QUESTION :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was in `if($homepage== ('loll')) then`

You should do:

```
if($a == $b){
echo $a;
}
else{
echo "nope...";
}
```

Full example:

```
$first = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$second = file_get_contents('http://www.wikipedia.org');

if($first == $second){
echo $first;
}


else{
    echo $second;
}
```